# Is multiple Binance api key possible to increase the limit rate?

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

One binance api key limited 1200 request per minute, How's if I create multiple api key for increse the limit rate? I can create 30 api key for my personal binance account. So I can increse the 1200 limit rate to 3,600 limit rate, is it works?

Comment: API limit is based on IP address. The document is crystal clear: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#limits

Comment: @halfelf how about if I have multiple binance account?

Comment: I fail to see there is any unambiguous meaning in the document. If doubt,  try that yourself.  https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ping is available without any authentication and gives the limitation used in HTTP response header.

Answer (score 0):

Run your own BNB Chain node and you have full, unthrottled, access. There is no way other service providers will increase their rate limits for you.